# why is .join(" "); not working on variable that points to reversed array?

Tags: javascript

If I chain it: reverser.split(" ").reverse().split(" "), it works. But, if I split, reverse, then join the variable -- it doesn't perform the join:

```
var s = "How are you";

function reverser(str){
  var reversed = str.split(" ");
  reversed.reverse();
   reversed.join(" ");
  return reversed;
};

console.log("does not work", reverser(s));

console.log("works", reverser(s).join(" "));
```

Comment: Error spotted: `'doesn't work '`

Comment: No. Either escape the quote `'doesn\'t work'` or use double quotes to wrap string `"doesn't work"`.

Comment: @Tushar the first one should be preferred. Second one is sometimes confusing for long Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.join()` function **returns** a string. It doesn't transform the target array into a string.

So,

```
reverser = reverser.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

joins returns a string and you have to store it in the variable.

```js
var s = "How are you";

function reverser(str){
  var reversed = str.split(" ");
  reversed.reverse();
   reversed=reversed.join(" ");
  return reversed;
};

console.log('doesn\'t work ', reverser(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

split() splits the string into array of strings. You need to store the resulting output everytime so that next operation can be performed right.

```
var s = "How are you";
function reverser(str){
var reverser = str.split(" ");
var revArray=reverser.reverse();
var revArrayJoined=revArray.join(" ");
return revArrayJoined;
};

console.log(reverser(s));
//output: you are How
```